# how to know when a coreanimation animation ends

Tags: animation, core-animation

I'm doing some animations with core animation, but I can't found a way to know with a notification or event when the animation block has finish, like in UIVIew animation block you have

```
setAnimationDidStopSelector:
```

how can I know this in core animation, thanks for any help

Answer (score 7):

If you are using a `CAAnimation` instance, look at the `animationDidStop:finished:` for its delegate.

```
CAAnimation * animation = [CAAnimation animation];
animation.delegate = yourDelegate; // could be self, for example.
[yourLayer setAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
```

In the example above, `yourDelegate` should implement the `animationDidStop:finished:` method to be able to detect the animation end.

Comment: Should it make any difference if it's a CATransition?  I can't seem to get animationDidStop:finished: to be called.