# how to display an image and hide it in the animation function?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want the image to be displayed and then hide and so on.  I have tried `nil` and `blank` with out success.  How can I accomplish this?

```
-(void) animationGlaw {

    glawBall.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@""], nil];
    glawBall.animationDuration = 0.50;
    glawBall.animationRepeatCount = 0;
    [glawBall startAnimating];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using just a transparent PNG for the final image.

Answer (score 1):

if you only want one image then none, you could try animating the opacity, and diong the animation very fast. If a fade out is acceptable then this would work even better.  [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/AnimatingLayers.html) is an example of animating the opacity.

you could also use the delegate to get notification when your animation ends and remove the image altogether, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129328/how-to-know-when-a-coreanimation-animation-ends) for an example of using the animationDidStop:finished: callback method.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is I just set height and width of image to 0.. Like this

[myImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(myX, myY, 0, 0)];